# Hi, I want to get the data from a json file, but I can't get it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an api in nodejs to getter data I need an authorization with token, but I don't know how to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://skillz-api.herokuapp.com/users", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            $("ul").append("<li>" + this['name'] + "</li><li>Age: " + this['age'] + '</li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Valider</button>&nbsp; <
            button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default btn-sm" > < span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" > < /span>Non valider</button > ');
        });
    });
});
```

My error is GET https://skillz-api.herokuapp.com/users 401 (Unauthorized)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First you must understand that an Authorization token must be passed by the GET Request's Headers, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers for more information.

You can build a jquery ajax request with headers, like this:

```
$.ajax("https://skillz-api.herokuapp.com/users", {
  headers: { "Authorization": "Your token here" }
}).then( (response) => {
    // do whatever you want here
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I do like that but I receive nothing  $.ajax("https://skillz-api.herokuapp.com/users", {
  headers: { "Authorization": "JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhZDhmMDM2NTQyNDQ4MDAyMGFmMjI0NSIsImlhdCI6MTUyNDE2NjcyNn0.5AEBY1HTbG_2FkBQvT1D7zDiRQNUYd1yCRdYbzdd-Us" }
}).then( (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});

Comment: error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
index.html:1 Failed to load https://skillz-api.herokuapp.com/users: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

Comment: Hi @MsAnis, you must then contact the developer who implemented the API!

If a status code 410 Unauthorized returns from that, it means you Token is not valid.

You must read the docs from that API and check what type of Authentication you need (Basic, Bearer Token, etc...)